# A problem that is in PSPACE but not known to be in PH?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

As we know Graph Isomorphism is in NP but it is not known to be NP-Complete or P-Complete. I was wondering if there are any problems that are known to be in PSPACE but not known to be PSPACE-Complete and not lie in PH?

Comment: Any PSPACE-complete problem? Maybe you ask the wrong question.

Comment: Are you asking whether PH=PSPACE?

Comment: I think the OP is merely asking whether there are any plausible candidates for separating PH and PSPACE

Comment: I believe there is a theorem which states that if PSPACE=PH then PH collapses.. I think I read it in Papadimitrou's book...

Comment: @Suresh, that is exactly what I am asking!

Comment: If you meant to ask for a problem analogous to GI, then perhaps you're asking for a problem that's not in PH and not PSPACE-complete. Problems complete for any class not known to be contained in PH, but contained in PSPACE, will work as an example. So take any problem complete for BQP, QMA, PP, etc.

Comment: Also, the existential theory of the reals is known to be in PSPACE but not PH.

Comment: @Robin, @Peter, both of these are answers, not comments :)

Comment: To the person whom that change their vote from upvote to downvote 1.5 years later.... Grow up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any problem that is MP-Complete, The class of decision problems such that for some #P function f, the answer on input x is 'yes' if and only if the middle bit of f(x) is 1. [Definition is from Complexity Zoo]. 
It has been shown that 
  PH
  ⊆
  MP
⊆
 PSPACE

.

Answer (score 23):

The [existential theory of the reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals) is known to be contained in PSPACE, but it is not known whether it is contained in PH. So take the existential theory of the reals, or any of the many equivalent problems.

Comment: What do you mean by a complete problem? The existential theory of the reals is a single problem, not a class.

Comment: @Emil: fixed now. There are enough equivalent problems that I think of it also as a complexity class, but I'm in the minority here.

Comment: I see, this makes sense.

Answer (score 19):

Any [PP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PP_%28complexity%29)-complete problem is trivially in PSPACE, but of course not known  to be PSPACE-complete. We also don't know whether or not PP is contained in PH either, though it follows from [Toda's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toda%27s_theorem) that PH is contained in P$^\text{PP}$. I believe the same also applies for [#P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P)-complete problems.

Answer (score 18):

Copying my comment:

If you meant to ask for a problem analogous to GI, then perhaps you're asking for a problem that's not in PH and not PSPACE-complete. Problems complete for any class not known to be contained in PH, but contained in PSPACE, will work as an example. So take any problem complete for BQP, QMA, PP, etc.

Answer (score 1):

ParitySat problem is to check if a SAT problem has an odd number of satisfiable assignments. PH is reducible to ParitySAT via randomized reductions by Toda’s work. This is a decision problem that is clearly strictly between PH and PSACE unless PH collapses.

Comment: Yes there are two corollaries of Toda's theorem which states that ParityP nor PP are in PH unless PH collapses to a finite level.